# .addClass causes flash in FireFox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, svg, blur

The following js block fades an image in then another div then adds a blur to the first image:

```
$('img.bg').load(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn(400,function(){
      $('div.foo').fadeIn(800, function() { 
        $('img.bg').addClass('blur');
   });  
  });
});
```

The blur class looks like this:

```
.blur {  
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);
-moz-filter: blur(2px);
-o-filter: blur(2px);
-ms-filter: blur(2px);
filter: blur(2px);

-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;  
transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
/*Firefox*/
filter: url(blur.svg#blur) 
}
```

Everything works great except the image in Firefox flashes when the svg blur class is added.  All other browsers are cool. Any strategies on how to avoid this?

Here is the SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Firefox is using the SVG filter and I suspect the transition  property doesn't apply. You'd have to use SMIL within the filter itself probably.

Comment: I started to make a fiddle but wasn't sure where to put the SVG code as its currently in a file.